# Binary Tree: Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have to create a copy constructor for a binary tree with the signature `bstt(const bstt& other)`. I attempted to do so, but I get the following error (in the last code block).

I thought I needed to change my helper function signature to include a `const`, but I tried a few combinations and none of them worked. How can I fix this?

Helper function:

```
void _postordercopy(NODE*& thisT, const NODE*& otherT)
{
 if(otherT==nullptr){
  thisT=nullptr;
 }
 else
 {
  NODE* tmp=new NODE;
  tmp->Key=otherT->Key;
  tmp->Value=otherT->Value;
  tmp->Left=otherT->Left;
  tmp->Right=otherT->Right; 
  tmp->isThreaded=otherT->isThreaded;

  _postordercopy(thisT->Left,otherT->Left);
  _postordercopy(thisT->Right,otherT->Right);
 }
}
```

Copy Constructor:

```
  bstt(const bstt& other)
  {
   Size=other.Size;
   _postordercopy(Root,other.Root);
  }
```

Error Message:

```
bstt.h:110:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘bstt<int, int>::_postordercopy(bstt<int, int>::NODE*&, bstt<int, int>::NODE* const&)’
```

Comment: In your function `bsst(const bsst&)`, the variable `other` is `const`. Meaning you have provided a contract to anyone calling this function that `other` will not be modified. `bsst(const bsst&)` cannot send `other` to `_postordercopy`, because it doesn't know if `_postordercopy` will make any changes to `other`. Change the function signature of `_postordercopy` so that the second parameter is `const Node*& otherT`, so that the copy constructor can honor its own `const` contract.

Comment: @John I get the error: ```no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘bstt<int, int>::NODE*’ to ‘const bstt<int, int>::NODE*&’```

Comment: I guess give it the signature it wants then.  I don't know the `const` rules as well as i thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `tmp` node in your `_postordercopy` function, assigning to it, but aren't doing anything with it.  Further, you are copying over the exact pointers for Left and Right.  That doesn't look right either.

I think this is what you really want for a recursive "copy the tree" function:

```
    NODE* copyTree(const NODE* other)
    {
         NODE* newTree = nullptr;

         if (other!=nullptr)
         {
             newTree = new NODE;
             newTree->Key = other->Key;
             newTree->Value = other->Value;
             newTree->isThreaded = other->isThreaded;
             newTree->Left = copyTree(other->Left);
             newTree->Right = copyTree(other->Right);
         }

         return newTree;
    }
```

And then in your copy constructor, just invoke it as follows:

```
    bstt(const bstt& other)
    {
        this->Size = other.Size;
        this->Root = copyTree(other.Root);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*I will assume that `bstt::Root` is declared as `NODE*`, as this seems most likely.*

The second parameter to `_postordercopy` is of type **`const NODE*&`**, a reference to a pointer to a constant `NODE`. What is the type of the argument you try to pass in? Since `other` is declared `const`, each of its members is `const`. So `other.Root` is a constant pointer to `NODE`, also known as **`NODE* const`** – the `const` is tacked on the far right of the declared type. This is incompatible with the parameter type. *(See [What is the difference between `const int*`, `const int * const`, and `int const*`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/1143272#1143272) for a more thorough discussion of this distinction.)*

The problem is that a non-constant reference cannot be initialized from a constant. Since `other` has to be `const`, you'd need to change the type of the function parameter to match what you give it. One solution is to move `const` so that it qualifies the pointer rather than the pointer-to object: `NODE* const &`. Another solution is to remove the ampersand, as that is a bit wasteful in this case: `const NODE*`. (The reference adds an extra layer of indirection that provides no benefit.) Think about what your function is supposed to do, and `const`-qualify whatever is supposed to not change. In this case, the node pointed to by the second parameter should not change.

While that resolves your immediate compiler error, there are other errors to address in your code. In addition, I would consider adding two accessor functions to get the root node. These functions could enforce `const` in a way that you do not get when accessing `Root` directly.

```
NODE *& get_root() { return Root; }
const NODE * const & get_root() const { return Root; }
```

The main difference is that the type of `other.Root` is `NODE * const`, which drops the `const`-qualifier for the node, whereas `other.get_root()` would yield a `const NODE * const`, which propagates the qualifier. At the same time, `this->get_root()` would yield a simple `NODE*` since `this` is not `const`-qualified. You get to use the same syntax, and the `const`-ness is propagated appropriately.